# How to find the number of queries executed since server startup in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Is there any way to get the number of queries executed since server startup in PostgreSQL?

In MySQL we get this information from status variable **[Questions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Questions), [Queries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Queries)**.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a way to do that.  The view `pg_stat_database` will give you info on the number of transactions and number of rows, but not the number of queries.  Also, the counters are reset only upon manual intervention, or upon crashes.  Clean restarts do not reset them.